# Inline CSS in HTML emails

Tags: html, css, email

What the best practice for styling an email campaign is.
Should I be adding all of my inline CSS in the body?
Or should I be Adding styles in my head and referencing them with classes?

I have already ruled out linking an external CSS document since most email clients do not support `<link>`.

Comment: caniemail.com may help you.

Answer (score -1):

the best practice is to apply the style in head tag, since that have a styling hierarchy than the inline-CSS and this will make your code readable and clean, but also if you are using third party CSS library like tailwindCss you will be using the inline-styling so if not using any third party CSS library stick with inline

Answer (score -1):

Adding style in head tag. That best practice if u not using library like tailwind or bootstrap